Volumetric flow rate given pressure in Darcy's law with Forchheimer term
Darcy's Law establishes a linear relationship between the pressure gradient and the volumetric flow rate in stationary, creeping, incompressible flow through porous media (1D for simplicity).
$$
Q = - \frac{kA}{\mu L} \nabla p.
$$
where $Q$ is the volumetric flow rate, $k$ is the permeability of the medium, $L$ is the length of the porous medium, $p$ is the pressure and $A$ is the cross sectional area of the porous medium.
In certain cases involving a higher Reynolds number (Wikipedia mentions Re > 1-10), a quadratic term, called the Forchheimer term is added:
$$
\nabla p = - \frac{\mu}{k}Q -\frac{\rho}{k_1}Q^2.
$$
Where $\rho$ is the density and $k_1$ is the intertial permeablity which is presumably determined experimentally.
In cases where volumetric flow rate is known, it seems intuitive to me that this would allow one to compute the pressure loss across a porous medium easily enough. However, I'm kind of puzzled about the reverse situation where the loss of pressure is known but one wishes to calculate volumetric flow rate. It seems like since we have a polynomial of degree two in $Q$, one should have in general two possible solutions for the volumetric flow rate with potentially complex values.
I guess my first question is for the case where two real solutions exist-- In practice, would we have to determine which of the two solutions empirically? Or is there a specific choice of one solution over the other that is preferable?
The follow-up question would be is there any clear connection between the Reynolds number (that is used to determine when the Forchheimer term is appropriate) and the solutions to this equation? For example, does the fact that Re > 1 imply that one cannot have complex solutions to the above quadratic equation?
Thanks again for any comments, and please feel free to point out any misconceptions because I am far from an expert in this field.

what is your assessment so far?

After playing around with some visualizations, I see that the Darcy-Forcheimer equation can be viewed as a parabola going through $\nabla p =0, Q=0$ and "opening down". This implies that there is only one solution where $\nabla p$ is negative, and the volumetric flow rate $Q$ is always positive.
When $\nabla p$ is positive, there is a full range of number of solutions (none, one, or two.)
I assume that practically speaking we just always orient ourselves so that $\nabla p $ is negative, so there is only one choice. Its interesting that this law is not "sign-symmetric" for the pressure.
